# Several values of irrational exponentiation

Tags: exponentiation, irrational-numbers

When talking about a number to a rational exponent, there are as many answers as the denominator of the exponent. Like the question: Is $9^{1/2}$ equal to $3$ or $-3$.

However when we have an irrational exponent like $2^{\sqrt2}$, I cant immediatly see more than one candidate solution: $e^{\sqrt2\log2}$. Are there any ways to interpret irrational exponents such that they give several candidate solutions?

Another way to state this question would be:

> are there more than one complex solution to $x^{1/p}=y$ for irrational $p$ and positive real $y$.

Comment: Yes but you really should be thinking of these things as functions of a complex variable.  What you want to look up is "branches" of analytic functions.

Comment: @GregoryGrant okay, so what would another candidate value of $2^{\sqrt2}$ be? It should obviously satisfy $x^{\sqrt{1/2}}=2$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant What I mean is, if a number is given one irrational number as exponent, can we get several possible values like we did with $\sqrt2$?

Comment: I suppose my question is equivalent to: are there more than one complex solution to $x^{1/p}=y$ for irrational $p$ and positive real $y$.

Comment: Try the complex number $z$ that has argument $2\pi/\sqrt{2}$ and modulus equal to $2$.  It lives somewhere in the 3rd quadrant of the complex plane.

Comment: Be careful not to confuse two things.  In fact $z=2^{1/2}$ really does have only one value (the positive one by convention), but that value satisfies $z^2=2$ and that equation has two solutions.  So you could play the same game with $z=2^2$, you could say it satisfies $z^2=16$.  But that does not mean $2^2=-4$.

Comment: I get that exponentiation isn't multivalued for real positive numbers, also I cant seem to come to the conclusion that your number should satisfy $x^{1/\sqrt2}=2$, since IIRC $(z^{a})^b\ne z^{ab}$ for complex z.

Comment: Do you know how to raise a complex number to a power?  If the power is $p$ then you multiply the angle by $p$ and raise the modulus to the $p$ power.  Look it up on the wiki page for complex numbers.  No need to use $(z^a)^b=z^{ab}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the real numbers field we have no ambiguity if we define (as usual) $a^{\frac{1}{2}}$ as the positive root of $a$ and $a^\alpha=e^{\alpha \log a}$ (for $a\le 0$) .

The problems come out when we go to complex numbers, as a consequence of the fact that $e^{i 2 k \pi}=1 \;\forall k \in \mathbb {Z}$. So $y=e^{i x}$ is a periodic function ( also for $x \in \mathbb{R}$) and is not invertible.

So, in the complex numbers field we have:
$$
y=e^x \iff y=e^x\cdot 1 = e^xe^{i2k\pi}=e^{x+i2k\pi}
$$
and the inverse '' function'' is a **multivalued function** : 
$$
\log y= x+i2k\pi
$$
we can find $x$ writing the complex number $y$ in polar form as $y=|y|e^{i\theta}$ so, from $|y|e^{i\theta}=e^x$ we have $x=\log |y| +i\theta$ and:
$$
\log y= \log |y| +i\theta+i2k\pi
$$

As a consequences of this fact  for $y,x,\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and  $y,x >0$ (this imples $\theta=0$), we have:
$$
y=x^\alpha \iff y=e^{\alpha\log x}=e^{\alpha(\log |x|+i2k\pi)}
$$

For $\alpha=1/2$ this gives the two square roots and for $\alpha$ irrational gives, in general, many values.

Answer (score 0):

Among arbitrary nonzero complex bases, there are an infinitude of $j$th powers for each irrational number $j$.

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers, $ab\neq0$, $e$ the base of the natural logarithm, $z$ be an integer, and $i^2=-1$

$$(a+ib)^j=(e^{\ln(a+ib)+i\pi+i2\pi z})^j=(e^{\ln(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})+iarg(a,b)+i2\pi z})^j=(e^{\ln(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})+i(arg(a,b)+2\pi z)})^j=e^{j\ln(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})+ij(arg(a,b)+2\pi z)}=(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})^j\cos(j(arg(a,b)+2\pi z))+i(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})^j\sin(j(arg(a,b)+2\pi z))$$

As stated above, $j$ is irrational, so for no value of $z$ except $z=0$ is $2j$ is an integer multiple of 2. so each nonzero complex has an infinitude of $j$th powers.